How to Compare Levels of One Factor Within Each Level of Another Factor in SAS glimmix?
I’m working with the following PROC GLIMMIX code in SAS:
proc glimmix data=my_data;
   class x1 x2 x3;
   model y = x1|x2;
   random x2;
   random x3;
   lsmeans x1*x2 / pdiff lines slicediff=(x2);
run;

I want to compare the effect of x1 within each level of x2. Specifically, I want to compare the levels of x1 within each individual level of x2 (e.g., compare x1 levels within x2=1, then within x2=2, and so on). I also want to see the grouping letters (for statistical differences) within each level of x2 for x1.
However, when I run this code, I’m getting a table with all levels combined, rather than separate comparisons within each x2 level. How can I modify my code to get these comparisons specifically within each level of x2 in SAS?
